# Eclipse cannot import jtwitter-yamba.jar in learning android

Tags: android

Im using Eclipse Juno and ADT 20 v2 My Yamba app which has no errors forces close immediately it is launched
My Logcat shows me in the Yamba app
Could not find class "winterwell.jTwitter.Twitter" referenced from method com.marakana.yamba.StatusActivity.onCreate 
I know many people here used Yamba to learn Android programming and d Oriellys site has no solutions
Is it the "Twitter("student","password") API root.." That is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this error by doing the following in Eclipse:

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export
then select "[x]jtwitter-yamba.jar - /path/to/jar"

Before it worked though, I had to do:
Project -> Clean...
Then ctrl-F11 to rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of [normal JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php). I think it's compatible with Yamba. You need to call Twitter.setAPIRootUrl() to point it at Yamba instead of Twitter.